# Emberjs 1.0 named templates: Cannot call method 'connectOutlet' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Named templates seem straightforward enough on paper, but for the life of me I can't make it work with emberjs 1.0, even with a trimmed down example (See jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/uNUQUhi/1/).

The handlebar templates:

```
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' id='index'>
    <div>{{outlet test}}</div>
  </script> 

  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='test'>
    <h1>A test</h1>
  </script>
```

...and the javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create() ;

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('test', {
      outlet:'test',
      into: 'index'
    });
  }
});
```

I must be missing something? But what? I couldn't find a working example of a named outlet (at least not one that worked with v.1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '`index`' template would be the 'normal' template that would be rendered by `IndexRoute`.  Since you're telling it to render the `'test'` instead, the `'index'` template is never rendered, and as a result Ember can't find your named outlet.  If you rename the `'index'` template to `'application'`, and the render `into : 'application'` everything works out.

http://jsbin.com/oLULeRo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, this works and your explanation is right on. I played a little bit and it turns out that (consistently with your answer), if I ask ember to render the index template `this.render('index');` **before** `this.render('test', etc.)` is executed I get it to work too